# How to deploy Specflow test to nightly build

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, build-process, specflow

How can I include Specflow tests into the Build process template for nightly build. 
I use VS 2012 and our nightly build run on Server 2008,

And I have some PowerShell script for it, but I don`t know how use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds incredibly vague. Does your powershell script run the build and test parts of your build?

Specflow will be run automatically as part of your nunit or mstest test runs. If you already have these and you are presenting the assemblies to the runner, it just happens.

personally I would suggest the easiest way is to download a copy of TeamCity, which if I remember correctly will be a free licence for just a single project. Just add your source code repo details, point a Visual studio step at your solution, a unit test step at your test dlls and a trigger for whenever you checkin and  will all happen automatically.